# Python increase parameter number in loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a text file where I want to replace some placeholder strings with data from an Excel file. Therefore I created this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

with open('testfile_1.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

dataframe1 = pd.read_excel('EXCEL_Data.xlsx', header=None)

values = range(5)
for i in values:
    filedata = filedata.replace('TEXT_1', dataframe1.iloc[1,1+i])
```

I now also want to iterate through "TEXT_1" since there is "TEXT_2", "TEXT_3", etc. which should all get different values from dataframe1.iloc[1,1+i]

But I don`t know how to iterate through TEXT_n. Can you please help me?

Thank you very much,

Jerry

Comment: Did you try to add another loop like "for n in range(n_max):" and then you call your replace method on filedata with an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) 'TEXT_{n}'  and the approriate dataframe value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need 'TEXT_i', you can use string concatenation: `'TEXT_' + str(i + 1)`. Other way is to use string interpolation: `f'TEXT_{i + 1}'`. Both methods will give you 'TEXT_1', 'TEXT_2', ..., 'TEXT_5'.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I went with the concatenation and it worked perfectly :)